# How I can do that animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to make an app, a kind of "Never have I ever" but with cards. When a "tricky" card appears I want to display an animation like that:

A image with text apears from the right side of the screen and stops on the centre. Waits a few seconds (3-4). In that waiting time it could size up a bit or something like that. Finally it goes out by the left side of the screen.

I have found out a similar animation in a game called Clash Royale.

http://i.imgur.com/8kB18dj.gifv

Thanks on advance.

*As note: I will develop it on Android Studio.

I need help doing it, examples por something like that. If you put the conde I will be thanked.

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I dont know how to start, Im not familiarized with animations

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want help with the basics of animation in android...
I know, that this is probably not exactliy what you wanted to hear or read, but you have to get into the huge topic 'animation' by yourself - I think you won't find someone, who does that specific animation for you.

A good way to start may be the following tutorial on how to make some real basic animation stuff:

[YouTube Tutorial Part 62](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlOM-CUlsBc&index=62&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A) (and the following)

I walked through this tutorial series by myself and it really helped me a lot.

Also [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html) seems to be a good tutorial about animations.

Good luck and have fun!